# qemu beagle sd card error

Tags: qemu, uefi

I am trying to run uefi code in qemu for beagle board using the following command

```
qemu-system-arm -M beagle -sd beagle_sd.img -serial stdio -clock unix
```

The sdcard holds uefi, which starts the shell, when this runs I am getting sd card error saying CMD17 is a wrong state. My log

`SD: CMD17 in a wrong state
sd_read_data: not in Sending-Data state (state=0)
----above line prints multiple times
sd_read_data: not in Sending-Data state (state=0)MmcIoBlocks(MMC_CMD65553): Error Device Error
EhcCreateUsb2Hc: capability length 0
EhcDriverBindingStart: failed to create USB2_HC`

Due to this my uefi shell only maps blk0 and blk1.
Any ideas on how to ahead?

Comment: So, I've not tested UEFI on the beagle QEMU machine ... do you specifically need this platform, or are you just after running UEFI on ARMv7 QEMU?

Comment: @unixsmurf I specifically need this platform. I do not know what the error is though, but I installed qemu on ubuntu 12.04 and it has qemu v1.5.0 I believe and that gives you CMD12 errors but still the sdcard mounts.

Comment: Wow - that's a really old QEMU :) So which version was the other one which failed to mount?

Comment: I am running 2.0.0 on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Ah, so a regression :/ In which case I would suggest building your own [QEMU 2.3](http://wiki.qemu.org/Download), and [reporting a bug](http://wiki.qemu.org/Contribute/ReportABug) if the problem persists. (sudo apt-get build-dep qemu-system-arm, ./configure --target-list=arm-softmmu, make, sudo make install)